# Make custom selected tab bar Item in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am working on an application using Swift which needs to have a TabBarController and when user will select a tab then that particular tab bar item shows a 3d visual effect (Although it will be an static image I guess) which contains shadow and that tab bar item will be bigger in size as well with different tint colour.

Please see the attached image.

[image]

I have searched a lot on internet but no luck. Please someone help :(

Comment: How did you eventually solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://cocoapods.org/pods/M13InfiniteTabBar

For as much as I do not like answers in the tone *It can't be done*, I feel that the specific of your screenshot, namely going outside of the `UITabbar` background, can't be done with `UITabBarController`.

Comment: I guessed the same. I think I will have to make a UI view and put imageviews and make logic by myself to get this effect.

Comment: Correct. There is no Pod that I know about which solves your immediate question. I would love to stand corrected. Please post a follow-up on the solution you elect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:`. Documentation found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:)